# Replace several elements in one column

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have one column with the names (First Name, Last Name) but sometimes there are the certificates, grades etc added to the names (ex: "John Smiths MBA"; "Susan Smiths FCA, ACCA"). The number of variable is countless but I identified the most common (there are many). Please help how to build the macro to clean this?
I've been using one by one, with:

```
Selection.Replace What:=" FCA,", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
```

But I guess there must be more efficient way to build this macro (and edit in case when new "unwanted extension is spotted).

Comment: If you have a list of items to replace you could put them in an array and loop through them.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim e, a, i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each e In Array("MBA", "FCA", "ACCA", ", ")
        Columns(1).Replace e, "", 2
    Next e

    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        .Value = Evaluate(Replace("IF(COLUMN(@)=1,TRIM(@),TRIM(PROPER(@)))", "@", .Address))
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! it seems to work well but only for a few abbreviations, I have to clean like about 100... with several added, I have an alert for the syntax. Do you know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Maybe using a temp worksheet and put the abbreviations in table and search based on that table.

Comment: Thx for your answers. despite having checked a couple of time, it appears there were some error I didn't notice. Now it's OK. But this method isn't perfect as it may delete some parts of people's names ("BA" for instance is a good example). From this point of vie, the code below (by Kwan Wan Sing) seems working better. I think the point is to mix/match both of your methods and it should be nearly perfect (nearly as there always will be some unexpected abbreviations added by people to their names :))

Comment: You may use Split to split the parts by space then loop through each part to check if it is existing in the array or not and if found to replace that part. But this would take longer time .

Answer (score 0):

I assume all the certificates and grades are 3 to 4 letters at the end of names, and it's all in UPPER case. Try the code based on this scenario.

```
Sub Test()

Dim name As String

i = 2
name = Range("A" & i).Value

While name <> ""

If Right(name, 4) = UCase(Right(name, 4)) Then
Range("A" & i).Value = Left(name, Len(name) - 4)

ElseIf Right(name, 3) = UCase(Right(name, 3)) Then
Range("A" & i).Value = Left(name, Len(name) - 3)
End If

i = i + 1
name = Range("A" & i).Value
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, Your assumption is unfortunately wrong (often more than 3-4 characters, often in lower cases or both, like CertRP).

Comment: Actually your method is working very well, it just need to be completed with the cases that are not falling into this rule. Thanks a lot!